# Is there a way to use titles on circuit drawing?

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-circuit

As you may know, one can use barriers in Qiskit to seperate gates on a circuit in a proper way. So, I was wondering is there a way to give a title to these "sections" seperated by barriers?

I provide an example in Figure below. Titles does not need to be exactly same with the ones in the Figure. It is just an example.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that the circuit drawer does not have a way to label "sections".

However, you can pass an arbitrary `matplotlib.axes.Axes` to the Matplotlib circuit drawer (only to that circuit drawer) where you can set and position your labels by hand. For your particular case, it looks something like this:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
height = 0.8
ax.text(-0.9, height, 'entanglement', size=14)
ax.text(2.5, height, 'init', size=14)
ax.text(4.5, height, 'transfer of\namplitudes', size=14)
ax.text(7, height, 'measurement', size=14)

circuit.draw('mpl', ax=ax)
```

[image]

You might have to adapt the `x` and `y` numbers (the first two parameters for `text`) to readjust their position.

Comment: I was looking for a built-in method which can automatically determine the positions of labels according to the barrier placements. But I guess this is the best solution we have right now. I appriciate your time and effort:)

Comment: Sorry, no build-in. The `ax` parameter was design as a catch-all for these use cases...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not looking as good as in the above mentioned solution, but much more convenient to use. The barrier can use a label parameter as shown below.

[image: barrier with label]